# How do i save a registered user to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, forms

I'm trying to add an user with an sqL query, and table, which works when i don't close the form. When i close the form it says that the user isn't registered, the code works, but i can't resolve this. It's as it doesn't save the users session data.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SchoolManagementApplication
{
    public partial class LoginDialog : Form
    {
        public LoginDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private bool VerifyUserCredentials(string username, string password, bool isLogin)
        {
            bool isValidUser = false;

            // Connection string
            string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.UnPConnectionString;

            // SQL query for login
            string loginQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table2] WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";

            // SQL query for registration
            string registerQuery = "INSERT INTO [Table2] (Username, Password) VALUES (@Username, @Password)";

            // Create a new connection
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                // Open the connection
                connection.Open();

                // If the user wants to login
                if (isLogin)
                {
                    // Create a new command
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(loginQuery, connection))
                    {
                        // Add parameters to the query
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                        // Execute the query
                        int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                        // Check if the result is greater than 0
                        if (result > 0)
                        {
                            isValidUser = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If the user wants to register
                else
                {
                    // Create a new command
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(registerQuery, connection))
                    {
                        // Add parameters to the query
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                        // Execute the query
                        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        // Check if the result is greater than 0
                        if (result > 0)
                        {
                            isValidUser = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return isValidUser;
        }

        private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the entered username and password
            string username = tbxUsername.Text;
            string password = tbxPassword.Text;

            // Verify the user credentials
            if (VerifyUserCredentials(username, password, true))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome: {0}", username));
                // Code to open the main application goes here
                this.Hide();
                MainInterface MI = new MainInterface();
                MI.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials. Please try again.");
                // Clear the textboxes
                tbxUsername.Text = "";
                tbxPassword.Text = "";
            }
        }
        private void Btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the entered username and password
            string username = tbxUsername.Text;
            string password = tbxPassword.Text;
            // Verify the user credentials
            if (VerifyUserCredentials(username, password, false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Successful registration: {0}", username));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registration failed. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 that you use SQL parameters. But: NEVER store passwords in plain in the database. use a salted hash instead.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware. Though this is for a school project, so entirely theoretical.

Comment: Is you database just an mdb file added to your solution? Then you presumably change the mdb file in your output directory and everytime you start the application from VS again the build process copies the template database from the solution overwriting your changed database with a fresh empty one.

Comment: _"Though this is for a school project, so entirely theoretical."_ - **That is no excuse**. Schools in particular _shouldn't teach such nonsense_. Use a password - then do it correctly. Or don't use a password - then at least students don't learn unsafe, dangerous behavior.

Comment: Oh and ... `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` => [can we stop using it](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)?

Comment: @Fildor: How does that (old?) document relate to: [Use **AddWithValue** whenever you want to add a parameter by specifying its name and value.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#:~:text=Use%20AddWithValue%20whenever%20you%20want%20to%20add%20a%20parameter%20by%20specifying%20its%20name%20and%20value.) ?

Comment: Oh, you _can_ use it. @Luuk I doubt it has lost its quirkyness over the last few years, though.